# SQL request foreign key on same table

Tags: sql, select, foreign-keys, primary-key

I got a table T, with the following columns
- ID_Employee (primary key)
- NAME_Employee
- ID_Manager (foreign key on the same table)

In order to display the rows of the table, I do :
SELECT ID_Employee , NAME_Employee, ID_Manager FROM T

But how can I display the NAME of the manager instead of his ID?
I'm a beginner on SQL :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.ID_Employee, 
  a.NAME_Employee, 
  b.ID_Employee AS ManagerID, 
  b.Name_Employee AS Manager
FROM T a
INNER JOIN T b
ON a.ID_Manager = b.ID_Employee
```